# Scroll view containing linearlayouts don't work

Tags: android, scrollview, android-scrollview

Why my scroll view doesn't scroll?

Here are my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b1"
                android:onClick="b1" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b2"
                android:onClick="b2" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b3"
                android:onClick="b3" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b4"
                android:onClick="b4" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b5"
                android:onClick="b5" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b6"
                android:onClick="b6" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b7"
                android:onClick="b7" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b8"
                android:onClick="b8" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b9"
                android:onClick="b9" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b10"
                android:onClick="b10" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b11"
                android:onClick="b11" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b12"
                android:onClick="b12" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b13"
                android:onClick="b13" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b14"
                android:onClick="b14" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b15"
                android:onClick="b15" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b16"
                android:onClick="b16" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b17"
                android:onClick="b17" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b18"
                android:onClick="b18" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b19"
                android:onClick="b19" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b20"
                android:onClick="b20" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b21"
                android:onClick="b21" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b22"
                android:onClick="b22" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b23"
                android:onClick="b23" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b24"
                android:onClick="b24" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/b25"
                android:onClick="b25" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Any idea?

Comment: are you sure there is something to scroll?

Comment: and also try with `android:fillViewport="true"` for your `ScroolView`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ScrollView cannot hold more than 1 child.. it needs 1 single child which hosts all other view.. Hope this help you

```
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/child">
<ImageView/>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I guess you mean `ScrollView`?! Because `LinearLayout` can definitely hold more than one child. Furthermore the code posted by the author already contains only one child-view inside the sv.

Answer (score 1):

Everything works fine, you just have not enough buttons to enable scrolling(you don't need it).
For see how scrolling works, use less screen size, or add more `Linearlayouts` with `buttons`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it works, but you may also try to add android:scrollbars="vertical" attribute to your LinearLayout